# Try to use predictive intelligence in MC org for collect abandoned cart info into SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, einstein-recommendations

I try to use predictive intelligence in MC org for collect abandoned cart info into SFMC PI_Abandoned Cart DE. Any suggestion?

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//10000XXXX.collect.igodigital.com/collect.js"></script><script>
      _etmc.push(["setOrgId", "10000XXXXX"]);
      _etmc.push(["trackCart", { "cart": [ // **ERROR : Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null**
      {"item" : "Xcode12340", "quantity":  "1", "price" : "599", "unique_id" : "cart1" },
      {"item" : "Xcode12342", "quantity":  "2", "price" : "399", "unique_id" : "cart1" }
      ]}]);
    </script>
```

Comment: what error you getting in your code

Comment: ** ERROR: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null** in collect.js in line 3 above.